# What do you call a cloth reminiscent of a scarf but rectangular a little like a blanket?

Tags: word-request

What do you call a cloth reminiscent of a scarf but rectangular a little like a blanket? I can't remember the word for it, but I am pretty sure there's a specific word for it. I don't think it's worn like a scarf, but maybe I am wrong on this.

Comment: [Kerchief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerchief)? Can you describe what you’re talking about with some more details or provide a picture?

Comment: It's not worn on the head, but worn on the body.

Comment: [Shawl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawl)?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Are there similar clothes to shawls or are they the only cloth worn like that?

Comment: Merriam-Webster synonyms of shawl:  
    serape (or sarape), stole, wrap,  cape, capote, cloak, frock, manteau, mantle

    burnoose (or burnous), capelet, capuchin, cowl, domino, joseph, manta, mantelet, mantilla, palatine, pelerine, pelisse, poncho, roquelaure, tippet

Comment: I don't think a cloak makes sense here, because it's not rectangular.

Comment: Some of those words are 'synonyms of _shawl_' in the sense that they are outer garments for the upper body, but not in the sense of being a simple piece of cloth. (A cowl is a type of hood, a pelisse is a type of coat, a cape is cut and sewn to fit round the shoulders...).